# Angular get route path - not resolved url

Tags: angular, angular-router

Is there a way in Angular to get the actual route in the NavigationEnd event instead of just the resolved url which event.url returns? I don't what the resolved params.

```js
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events
    .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    .subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
        // how to get route path? Such as 'someList/:id'
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way but

```
this.router.routerState.snapshot.root.firstChild.routeConfig
```

will get you the route config for the current route which has the configured path,

Answer (score -1):

You want something like this?

```
router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
  console.log(event);
  if (event instanceof NavigationEnd ) {
    this.currentUrl = event.url;
  }
});
```

Comment: No. That returns the resolved path, I want the path configured in routeconfig.

Comment: you can get that from router links?

Comment: How do I do that for the current path?

Comment: parse it and use this snippet as the anchor?

Comment: Do you have an example? I want to use it for tracking loaded routes, and not specific urls.